# how to fix an invalid syntax when giving the location of my files to the notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run a drifter simulation by doing a numerical experiment and whenever I try to give the variable "loc" the location of the files (four '.nc' files) that I have in my computer it keeps telling me that there is a syntax error. How could I run my own files in the jupyter notebook?

I'm running a Tracpy enviroment made with python and anaconda and at first, I would upload the files to direct access and downloading web but also kept telling me the files were innaccesible or not found.

```
loc = C:\Users\acer\Documents\Tesis

File "<ipython-input-1-45e6bc31672d>", line 1
    loc = C:\Users\acer\Documents\Tesis
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm expecting to be able to run these files to generate a Yucatan Channel map but when it ends running the map is blank.

Answer (score 0):

- The `SyntaxError` occurs because `loc` is not properly formatted as a `str` or `pathlib` object
- Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) part of the standard library, to work with files and directories.

  - [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

#### Code:

- `r` at the front means `raw`, which is used because of the Windows backslashes

  - `loc = 'C:/Users/acer/Documents/Tesis'` doesn't require `r`, but it's a pain to change all those slashes

```py
from pathlib import Path

loc = r'C:\Users\acer\Documents\Tesis'

# this will find all the .nc files in the directory
files = Path(loc).glob('*.nc') 

# A loop will allow you to access each file
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'C:\Users\acer\Documents\Tesis'

In the loop do I have to change the "file" for the name of the files or something like that?